# 10 digest iterations reached in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a login form that I want to show only is user had logged out or is not logged in

```
  <form ng-submit="signInUser()" name="userForm" novalidate ng-if="showForm()">
</form>
```

`showForm()` is a function that looks like this:

```
 $scope.showForm = function(){

      if($localStorage.userInfo === null || $localStorage.userInfo === undefined){
        return true;
      }else{
       $scope.signInUser();
       //$state.go('Deployment')
        return false;
      }
    }
```

`$scope.signInUser()` calls a get api which gets data and transitions it to  `Deployment` state using `$state.go('Deployment', {}, {reload:true});`

Now, either I can call `signInUser` again or directly go to Deployment state.

In both the cases I get an error that says, `10 digest iterations reached`.

This is how I route:

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('Login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl'
  })

  .state('Deployment',{
    url:'/deployment',
    templateUrl:'templates/deployment.html'
  })
  .state('Bill',{
    url:'/bills',
    templateUrl:'templates/bills.html'
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
           var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $state.go('Login');
        });


});
```

What seems wrong with the current code? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You could simply do `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');` ...does `signInUser` is an ajax call?

Comment: No, That does not solve the problem. There's an http call in signInUser

Comment: Just check if `signIn()` has returned a value and assign it to a `$scope.loggedIn = true`, otherwise `$scope.loggedIn = false`, then in your view set `ng-if="loggedIn"` instead of using a function in your `ng-if`